# Makefile for interpreter in C

Tags: c, makefile

My Makefile looks like this

```
opsh:   shellparser.c main.c util.c errors.c
    gcc -std=c99 -oopsh shellparser.c main.c util.c errors.c -lreadline -ltermcap

PREFIX = /usr/local

.PHONY: install
install: opsh
    mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin
    cp $< $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin/opsh

.PHONY: uninstall
uninstall:
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin/opsh
```

The project is [available on github](https://github.com/montao/opsh/tree/985345c09c1387711a8f23056fca05e2ec9ef8a0). The statistics are

```
$ cloc .
      30 text files.
      30 unique files.                              
      45 files ignored.

http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.60  T=0.08 s (283.8 files/s, 123084.0 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C                                6            837           2025           7105
C/C++ Header                     7             53             15            143
Bourne Shell                     7              6              6             93
yacc                             1              8              2             56
CMake                            1             12              0             28
make                             1              3              0             10
YAML                             1              1              0              5
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                            24            920           2048           7440
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you targeting GNU Make, or are you aiming for portability?

Comment: @200_success I feel that I must have portable code. I don't have enough experience to make the decision. I suppose I rather want portability. The project is a command-line interpreter (a custom Unix shell) and my goal is to learn autotools and how to package it for portability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You should investigate whether GNU Make (or whichever Make implementation your users are supposed to use) has a special variable for *all dependencies of the current rule*, so that you don't need to list the source files twice.
- The command line for gcc is missing the `-Wall -Wextra -O2` options to catch common mistakes and to make the program run faster.
- If you want the Makefile to be portable to systems other than GNU Linux on x86_64, you should switch to GNU autoconf, but that's a lot of work. If your project is just a toy project, it's fine as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying a particular compiler and flags, it's good practice to use Make's standard variables `CC` and `CFLAGS`, to allow users to pass in their preferences as necessary.  Assuming that your source files are separately compilable, we usually separate compilation and linking, so that a change to `shellparser.c` doesn't require a rebuild of `util.c` and `errors.c`, for example.  With those changes, the first two lines can be replaced with

```make
CFLAGS += -std=c99
LDLIBS += -lreadline -ltermcap

opsh: shellparser.o main.o util.o errors.o
```

Built-in rules will do the rest.

---

If you have any header files, you'll want to make them dependencies of the object files they affect.  You can do this manually, but a low-maintenance approach is to generate dependencies automatically.  That's a whole question in itself, but since you're using GCC, you will probably want [Combined Compilation and Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/#combine):

```make
DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $*.Td
COMPILE.c = $(CC) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
POSTCOMPILE = @mv -f $*.Td $*.d && touch $@

OBJECTS := shellparser.o main.o util.o errors.o
opsh: $(OBJECTS)

%.o : %.c
%.o : %.c %.d
        $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
        $(POSTCOMPILE)


%.d: ;
.PRECIOUS: %.d
include $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)
```

---

The `install` target would be better to use the `install` command, in order to set the correct ownership and permissions on the created files:

```make
install: opsh
        install -m755 -D -d $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin
        install -m755 $< $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin/opsh
```

---

All Makefiles should have `.DELETE_ON_ERROR`, to cause the target to be removed if its recipe fails.  Otherwise, a subsequent make would use in improperly-built target. The only case when you wouldn't want `.DELETE_ON_ERROR` is when debugging a compiler; it may be necessary to inspect the incomplete or invalid target file.

---

## Modified Makefile

With the above changes, you have

```make
OBJECTS := shellparser.o main.o util.o errors.o
opsh: $(OBJECTS)

CFLAGS += -std=c99
LDLIBS += -lreadline -ltermcap

DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $*.Td
COMPILE.c = $(CC) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
POSTCOMPILE = @mv -f $*.Td $*.d && touch $@

OBJECTS := shellparser.o main.o util.o errors.o
opsh: $(OBJECTS)

%.o : %.c
%.o : %.c %.d
        $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
        $(POSTCOMPILE)


%.d: ;
include $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)

.PRECIOUS: %.d

install: opsh
        install -m755 -D -d $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin
        install -m755 $< $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin/opsh

uninstall:
        $(RM) $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin/opsh

.PHONY: install uninstall
.DELETE_ON_ERROR
```